# Using NOT LIKE on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Got a search where I'm right now building my own version of the query filtering that exists in for example Boolean search. I mean that I can do `office +sweden` that should mean that `sweden` has to exists. We can't use BOOLEAN search for reasons that are outside of this question.

Say that I have a table called `documents` that have two columns on it `content` and `notes`. When I type, in my search bar, `+office +sweden` I do something similar to this that works:

```sql
SELECT * FROM documents
WHERE (content LIKE '%office%' or notes LIKE '%office%') AND
      (content LIKE '%sweden%' or notes LIKE '%sweden%')
```

This works perfectly so far. This will only give me documents where `office` **AND** `sweden` is somewhere either in `content` or `notes`.

Now I want to do the same thing but with a minus. For example if I search for `office -sweden` I want to get all the documents that **contains** `office` and **does not contain** `sweden` in either `contents` or `notes` (yes, with the wildcard as well).

I have tried multiple ways without getting it to work properly. I've tried with `NOT LIKE` for example without getting it to work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM documents
WHERE (content LIKE '%office%' or notes LIKE '%office%') AND
      (content NOT LIKE '%sweden%' or notes NOT LIKE '%sweden%')
```

Feels like the `or` is messing it up with this one. I've also tried using `AND NOT`

```sql
SELECT * FROM documents
WHERE (content LIKE '%office%' or notes LIKE '%office%') AND NOT
      (content LIKE '%sweden%' or notes LIKE '%sweden%')
```

I had high hopes about the `AND NOT` but this doesn't work as expected either.

Hope it's clear what I want to do. Get all the documents that contain `office` but does not contain `sweden` using `LIKE`.

## Solution

Turns out that there were nothing wrong with the queries itself. I had more fields in the query that could be null. I omitted these fields in the question to try and make it easier to understand. If you have fields that can contain `null` make sure to handle that like Gordon says below.

I handled `null` fields with the `IFNULL` operator like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM documents
WHERE (content LIKE '%office%' or notes LIKE '%office%' or nullfield LIKE '%office%') AND
      NOT (IFNULL(content, '') LIKE '%sweden%' or IFNULL(notes, '') LIKE '%sweden%' or IFNULL(nullfield, '') LIKE '%sweden%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `not like`:

```
SELECT *
FROM documents
WHERE (content LIKE '%office%' or notes LIKE '%office%') AND
      (content NOT LIKE '%sweden%' and notes NOT LIKE '%sweden%');
```

Or if you prefer:

```
SELECT *
FROM documents
WHERE (content LIKE '%office%' or notes LIKE '%office%') AND
      NOT (content LIKE '%sweden%' or notes LIKE '%sweden%');
```

One caveat:  `NOT LIKE` ignores `NULL` values just as `LIKE` does.  So if the values can be `NULL`, you need to take that into account.

Comment: I think I `LIKE` this answer +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon! The issue was not the query but that I had other fields that could be `null` that was also part of the query that I just omitted in the question to make it look easier. I have added a solution on my post and given you the approve.